# Winforms, control only working with breakpoint

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I created a custom Toast Notification for my Winforms application, whenever a custom result is returned, I use a ShowMessage extension to display the notification.

On my login screen, I have a unlock application button that will show the toaster message whenever the password is incorrect.

When I put a breakpoint right before the result.ShowMessage(); the notification appears. But when I remove the breakpoint, it does not appear anymore. I do not change any debug values.

How can I resolve this? I did try implementing a thread.sleep but it did not change anything, the notification only appears when I insert a breakpoint and continue over it.

It is worth noting that the notification works perfectly everywhere else in the application.

Code for the Unlock Application:

```
private void UnlockApplication()
    {
        var result = new Business.Server.User().Get(_loginModel.UserName, _loginModel.Password.Encrypt());
        if (result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            // Perform log in process
        }
        else
        {
            result.ShowMessage(); //Only works when I put breakpoint here 
        }
    }
```

Code for ShowMessage extension

```
public static void ShowMessage<T>(this Models.Result<T> result) where T : class
    {
      Helpers.ToasterNotificationHelper.ShowNotification(result.ResultTypeKey.ToDescription(), result.Message, result.ResultImage(), result.ResultColor(), result.ResultTypeKey == Enums.ResultTypeEnum.Warning ? 5000 : 2500);  
    }

public static void ShowNotification(string header, string message, Image icon, Color backgroundColor, int durationInMilliseconds = 1000)
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms[0] is MyApplication)
            {
                var toasterNotification = new ToasterNotificationControl(header, message, icon, backgroundColor);
                (Application.OpenForms[0] as MyApplication).toastNotificationCollectionControl1.AddNotification(toasterNotification, durationInMilliseconds);
            }
        }
```

My Toast Notification control is a DevExpress flyout panel control that gets added to the Main application form

Comment: Is this method "Business.Server.User().Get...." asynchronous?

Comment: Seems like you need to `await` the task to be completed

Comment: No, it is not, I have tried making the method asynchronous but it did not work

Comment: @TuxedoMan When "UnlockApplication()" called?

Comment: On Click from the Unlock Button

Answer (score 0):

Your "Get(_loginModel.UserName ..." seems to be asynchronous. Try to do the next to make the call awaitable:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task UnlockApplicationAsync()
{
    var result = await new Business.Server.User().Get(_loginModel.UserName, _loginModel.Password.Encrypt());
...
```

Comment: I have tried doing this, unfortunately, it still does not show. It still only shows with the breakpoint

Comment: @TuxedoMan what "ShowMessage()" does?

Comment: Show Message adds the notification control to the parent form, performs the slide out animation, remains visible for 5 seconds, and then removes it from the parent form.

Comment: @TuxedoMan I don't like "if (Application.OpenForms[0] is MyApplication) ...". Does your code always get inside this "if"?

Comment: Yes, it is a redundant check, but it is a standard we follow for our "is-as" implementations to prevent any unexpected actions

Comment: @TuxedoMan does your code get inside this "if" without a breakpoint right before the result.ShowMessage()?

Comment: @TuxedoMan So... the problem is with "Application.OpenForms[0]" at this moment.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?